# Could one solve a first-order equation with variable coefficients using SymPy?

Tags: python, sympy, symbolic-math, calculus

One can use SymPy in order to solve ODE's. My question on the topic of symbolic computing is; Can one solve a first-order equation with variable coefficients using Sympy? Note this is a special case of ODE. For example, if I had an equation like the one below

[image]

How would I set up solving such an equation using SymPy if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

```
In [51]: p = Function('p')                                                                                                        

In [52]: x = Symbol('x')                                                                                                          

In [53]: p = Function('p')                                                                                                        

In [54]: x, sigma, gamma, C1 = symbols('x, sigma, gamma, C1')                                                                     

In [55]: eq = Eq(p(x).diff(x), -2/sigma**2 * (C1 + gamma*p(x)))                                                                   

In [56]: eq                                                                                                                       
Out[56]: 
d          -2⋅(C₁ + γ⋅p(x)) 
──(p(x)) = ─────────────────
dx                  2       
                   σ        

In [57]: dsolve(eq, p(x))                                                                                                         
Out[57]: 
                ⎛     2⋅x⎞
              γ⋅⎜C₂ - ───⎟
                ⎜       2⎟
                ⎝      σ ⎠
       -C₁ + ℯ            
p(x) = ───────────────────
                γ
```

Note that C2 is the arbitrary constant (to be given by the initial conditions).